# What is the best method to treat cutting your nails too short?

Tags: personal-care, comfort

This is one of the most annoying mistakes that I make on a regular basis, but I have yet to find a way to effectively deal with it.  I currently put neosporin on it, and then I wrap it very tightly with a band-aid.  This is not very effective, and it actually doesn't really do much at all for me.

Does anyone have a more suitable method for dealing with this?

The obvious answer is to not do it in the first place, but...it happens.

Comment: How to treat an injury sounds like a great question for our Health site ([super-secret access link, shh....](http://health.stackexchange.com/grant-beta-access?key=0d2a964870d66d1710519cfe956a6ca5)), but this doesn't really sound like something that needs a life hack.